# How do I download iTunes podcasts to my iPod?

Tags: sync, itunes, ipod, podcasts

I'm going on holiday tomorrow and I won't have Internet, so I downloaded 40 podcasts from iTunes. I've plugged in my iPod and booted up iTunes, but it won't sync them. It's synched my newest music, but it won't download the podcasts when I click Sync.

How do I get them on to my iPod?

Edit: I tried ticking the podcasts then syncing the iPod with "only ticked songs", but that just removed most of my iPod's library and didn't add the podcasts.

Comment: @ Keir Bourne - Is the "Automatically include" set to "All" vs all unplayed or all new?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you have Podcasts checked to sync with iPod.

Connect iPod to computer.

Go to iTunes

Select your ipod (#1)

Go to the Podcast bubble at the top (#2)

Click the Sync check box (#3)
[image]

Click on Summary (#4)

Click on Sync (#5)

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't seen the bubbles at the top of the iPod screen.

Comment: @KeirBourne don't feel bad. It's one of the worst UI decisions made by Apple.